# Msbuild 10 and Nant doesnt copy weboutput

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, nant

I cant seem to get Nant to copy my web solution to an output folder, such as a Test server. It simply will not copy the files, even though the build succeeds.

According to the docs /p:WebProjectOutputDir should do it.

Thanks in advance.

```
<echo message="Compiling ${msbuild.workingdir}\${package.name}.sln - Copy to ${development.path}"/>
<exec program="msbuild.exe" basedir="${msbuild.path}" workingdir="${msbuild.workingdir}">
  <arg value="/p:Configuration=Test" />
  <arg value="/p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=True" />
  <arg value="/noconsolelogger" />
  <arg value="/v:d" />
  <arg value="/logger:${lib.nant.path}\loggers\Rodemeyer.MsBuildToCCnet.dll"/>
  <arg value="/t:rebuild;ResolveReferences;_CopyWebApplication"/>
  <arg value="/p:OutDir=\\latchford\Drop\Club.Registration.DailyBuild\current\bin" />
  <arg value="/p:WebProjectOutputDir=\\latchford\Drop\Club.Registration.DailyBuild\current\" />
  <arg value="${package.name}.sln"/>
</exec>
<property name="msbuild.output.file" value="${msbuild.workingdir}/msbuild-output.xml"/>
<move if="${file::exists(msbuild.output.file)}" file="${msbuild.output.file}" todir="${log.dir}" failonerror="false" overwrite="true" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.The OutDir property must end with a trailing slash: /p:OutDir=..\current\bin\
2.Parameter UseWPP_CopyWebApplication doesn't required just to copy to your output
3.It seems that enough only rebuild target to call

```
<exec program="msbuild.exe" basedir="${msbuild.path}" workingdir="${msbuild.workingdir}">
  <arg value="/p:Configuration=Test" />
  <arg value="/noconsolelogger" />
  <arg value="/v:d" />
  <arg value="/logger:${lib.nant.path}\loggers\Rodemeyer.MsBuildToCCnet.dll"/>
  <arg value="/t:rebuild"/>
  <arg value="/p:OutDir=\\latchford\Drop\Club.Registration.DailyBuild\current\bin\" />
  <arg value="/p:WebProjectOutputDir=\\latchford\Drop\Club.Registration.DailyBuild\current\" />
  <arg value="${package.name}.sln"/>
</exec>
```

Comment: Thanks,  only just back to this now. This worked a treat thanks for your help.

Comment: @Dr. can you close the issue?